# Is there any performance difference between using Apple Java or Oracle Java for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can imagine that Apple Java might be better tuned for Macs but Oracle Java might be more active development.  I'm specifically wondering about video and 3D performance for Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Apple Java", Java for OS X is maintained by Oracle.

Even [Apple's page about Java](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204036) says that you can get it from Oracle's java page.

[image: "Get Java for your Mac", "Download Java for OS X directly from Oracle"]

Also if you are wondering about the old [Java SE 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572), it is old, and should be used if apps specifically require that.

[image: "Note: You can also download legacy Java SE 6 from Apple if you’re using an app that specifically requires this unsupported, out-of-date version."]

Also, Minecraft uses Oracle Java.